# Find the general term of the sequence defined by $x_0 = 3, x_1 = 4$ and $x_{n+1} = x_{n-1}^2- nx_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Find the general term of the sequence defined by $$x_0 = 3, x_1 = 4\quad  \&\quad  x_{n+1} = x_{n-1}^2- nx_n \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

I realized this is not a homogeneous recursion relationship.
I don't know if it's the right expression, but it has variable coefficients, and it's not linear.

Is there another method to solve this without induction?

Comment: Your [prior post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359147/number-sequence-integers) was closed because it was unreadable.  This one is unreadable too.

Comment: I have a difficulty with that. Has the post improved now?

Comment: No.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: Did you write out some terms of this?

Comment: I just made some comments of mine

Comment: It's always a good idea to write out the first few terms of a recursion.  In this case, it makes the answer obvious.

Comment: Yes! I already used this tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We prove by induction that $x_n=n+3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $x_0=3=0+3$ and $x_1=4=3+1$, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=n+3$ and $x_{n+1}=n+4$, we have
$$ x_{n+2}=x_n^2-(n+1)x_n=(n+3)^2-(n+1)(n+4)=n+5=(n+2)+3 $$
This ends the induction.

Comment: Does it have another method?

Comment: I think this is the easiest method, calculating the first terms $x_2=5$, $x_3=6$, $x_4=7$ quickly gives you the result.